# Forcing Google Cloud storage to respond with Content-Encoding

Tags: http-headers, google-cloud-storage, gzip, unreal-engine4, content-encoding

I would like to serve some Unreal-generated HTML5 files using Google Cloud storage. Some of the files are gzip-encoded, and one of the javascript files checks that every file which ends with `gz` is returned with `Content-Encoding: gzip`. I don't want to change these files.

In GC UI, I set the Content-Encoding (and Content-type) fields in file metadata. To prevent decompressive transcoding I also set Cache-Control: no-transform. Despite that, the Content-Encoding header is still missing. (full header below). Is there anything else I can do to make Google Cloud respond with Content-Encoding?

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
X-GUploader-UploadID: some hash
Date: Sun, 24 Feb 2019 01:06:05 GMT
Cache-Control: no-transform
Expires: Mon, 24 Feb 2020 01:06:05 GMT
Last-Modified: Sun, 24 Feb 2019 00:52:29 GMT
x-goog-generation: 1550969549021835
x-goog-metageneration: 3
x-goog-stored-content-encoding: gzip
x-goog-stored-content-length: 99750206
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
x-goog-hash: crc32c=oobjmg==
x-goog-hash: md5=fN6srk43sVaYDVNgpXtdLQ==
x-goog-storage-class: REGIONAL
Accept-Ranges: none
Server: UploadServer
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: Does your client set Accept-Encoding:gzip ?
If not, Google will decompress the object when it's being served.

Comment: I think it does and I don't control that, however if I understand the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding#decompressive_transcoding) correctly, setting `no-transform` has a precedence over `Accept-Encoding`.